# List all SVN change-sets of Mylyn task in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, changeset, mylyn

I'm evaluating Mylyn SVN change-set feature. Whenever I checks-in change-set into SVN, Mylyn automatically adds commit message based on active task. In "SVN history" panel, I can see the commit message for each change-sets and I can open Mylyn task using "Open corresponding task" action of context menu. This is fine. I'm looking for a way to see all change-sets associated with a particular Mylyn task in Eclipse. Mylyn documentation or Google did not give any valuable info. If my understanding is correct, this is not an implemented feature of Mylyn. Is there any Eclipse plug-in for this? any other solutions/workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may come with Mylyn 3.7 (sub-project Mylyn-Versions), see: http://eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?projectid=mylyn.versions